# If functions compose both ways to make automorphisms, are they isomorphisms?

Tags: functions, category-theory, groupoids, morphism

Let's say that we have morphisms $f:A \to B$ and $g : B \to A$ such that $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are both automorphisms (an automorphism is a morphism that is both iso and endo). Are $f$ and $g$ isomorphisms?

The converse is true. Also they won't necessarily be inverses.

If it is not true in general, which categories is it true for? (It is vacuously true if the category is a groupoid.)

Comment: This is a special case of the 2-out-of-6 property of isomorphisms.

Answer (score 5):

$f\circ g$, being an automorphism, has an inverse $h$. Then $(h\circ f)\circ g$ is the identity, so $g$ has a left inverse and hence is a split monomorphism. Similarly, $g\circ f$ has an inverse $h'$, so $g\circ (f\circ h')$ is the identity, hence $g$ has a right inverse, hence is a split epimorphism. Thus $g$ is an isomorphism. Obviously this is a symmetric argument so the same applies to $f$.

Comment: $g$ has a left inverse, so it's mono. $g$ has a right inverse, so it's epi. How do you conclude it's an iso?

Comment: @IttayWeiss It's split mono and split epi, so it's an isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, but the way you worded your answer hides the split part. You deduce monichood, epichood, and then isoness. But generally, monic+epic does not imply iso. Split monic+split epic does.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Updated, thanks.